# CSS and jQuery: document.height not reporting properly? div won't stretch vertically

Tags: jquery, css, html

Oddly enough I can't seem to find anyone with this issue. O_o

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/nevqPwii)

Code leaves a gap between the end of #main and the end of the actual page on IE, Chrome (and Safari), but not on Firefox.

Vanilla CSS has `html, body{ min-height: 100%; height: auto !important; }`. `#content` is `position: relative` inside `#main`.

Trying to get `#main` to stretch from the top to the bottom of the page.

Edit: After playing with it more, it seems to me that everything depends on #content having its entire content loaded before the CSS-change calculations take place. Switching from one page to another allows Chrome (and Safari) to set the proper height for #main. Is there any way I can 'tell the code to wait'? Although I'm not sure if this fixes the problem with IE

Comment: Just a guess, but one thing I'd try in between curses would be to see if `$('body').height()` returns anything different. (Probably not.)

Comment: Since I took a break in swearing and performing rituals in hopes that IE will be standards-compliant in the next six-hundred years, I can tell you that a `$(window).load(function() { $('html').prepend($(document).height()+' - '+$(window).height()+' - '+$('body').height()); });` gave results of '928 - 924 - 500' in IE and '1102 - 948 - 500' in Firefox. It's like IE doesn't know the proper height to report. Which is why I mentioned the absolute positioning. Would that make a difference?

Comment: Usually when I run into problems like this, I try to take a step back and make sure I'm not doing something crazy with my CSS. You really shouldn't need to adjust the height of your page unless you're trying to do a two-column equal-height layout sort of thing.

Why is your `#content` div absolutely positioned?

Comment: I changed it to relative sometime shortly after posting this, but it doesn't change the fact that setting `$('#main').css('height', document.height)` seems to be setting to `window.height` instead. Also there is no way that I'm aware of to make #main have the same height as a relative or absolutely positioned child div. I've tried setting `html, body { height: 100% } #main { min-height: 100%; height: auto; }` to make sure. So it looks like I'm forced using jQuery for setting the CSS in this particular case.

Comment: do you have a reset.css somewhere in your html?

Comment: `* { padding: 0; margin: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
html,body { padding: 0; margin: 0; border: none; min-height: 100%; height: auto !important; } ` Aside from this, no. It didn't seem necessary for what I was doing, since it doesn't incorporate anything else that might cause an issue.

Comment: Could you give an example of the markup please.

Comment: `<html><body><div id='main'><div id='content'>Content of page.</div></div></body></html>` - Like this? Aside from something else `position: absolute` in the layout, it really is that simple. I'll note that `#content` is `position: relative; top: 135px; left: 300px`

Comment: @Zydeco Have you tried `$('window').height()`? I've had issues before with `document` height not behaving correctly.

Comment: After playing with it more, it seems to me that everything depends on `#content` having its entire content loaded before the CSS-change calculations take place. Switching from one page to another allows Chrome (and Safari) to set the proper height for `#main`. Is there any way I can 'tell the code to wait'? Although I'm not sure if this fixes the problem with IE.

Comment: You shouldn't need Javascript.

Comment: I do in fact require it as plain CSS does not cover the requirements unless voodoo is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="content">
                <p>content area</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS

```
html, body {height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0}
#main {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    width: 1024px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0; 
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-512px
}
#content {margin: 135px 0 0 300px}

/* for illustrative purposes */
#main {background-color: #CDE}
```

Check out the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/UB975/6/

Comment: I would show off my CSS in fiddle, but I broke their server. Anyway, `#content` has `min-height: 555px;` and `position: relative; top: 135px;` and doesn't go past that (the min-height) unless the content requires it. `#main` is supposed to `min-height: 100% height: auto;` so it stretches with `#content` if necessary, but vanilla CSS doesn't allow it to work like this, possibly because of the positioning.

Comment: It seems to not want to update, so please put more than 'content area' in there. Try about ten or so paragraphs of Lorem for the full effect.

Comment: I updated the fiddle (new link): absolutely positioned the `#main` and used margin on `#content` instead of positioning. Also added mooooooore content.

Comment: Margin is a great idea, but now is there any way to fix this so that #main starts in the proper place? (`top: 0px;`) http://jsfiddle.net/HxhvE/

Comment: It does. Did you check my latest fiddle link?

Comment: `#content` does, but you have `#main` as `position: absolute;` when in fact it's . . . well, have you seen my fiddle? It gives the proper styles for `#main`.

Comment: I see that you have `#main` positioning as relative but is there any reason why it can't be absolute? What is `#main`'s proper place?

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to be centered with a width of 1024px, and as far as I know the 'proper' way to do that is as I've done, `width: 1024px; position: relative; margin: 0 auto;`. I don't believe you can achieve this effect with absolute positioning considering you can't possibly account for varying resolutions that way.

Comment: Ok, I get it. You can still position `#main` absolutely you just need to do `left: 50%; margin-left: -512px` to get it centered. See my updated answer and fiddle.

Comment: You awesome thing! I never would have thought of something like that for pure CSS. Thank you for taking the time to educate me (and save me from a million more headaches). So glad that I don't have to use Javascript as a fix for this. Now if I can just figure out how to get a gradient background to be 'fixed' in Internet Exploder I'd be set. Hitting Google. ;)

Comment: Zydeco, you are very welcome. I'm glad it worked out for you.